# Loop through Pandas dataframe and copying to a new dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe `df` with 6000+ rows of data with a datetime index in the form `YYYY-MM-DD` and with columns `ID`, `water_level` and `change`.

I want to:

1. Loop through each value in the column `change` and identify turning points
2. When I find a turning point, copy that entire row of data including the index into a new dataframe e.g. `turningpoints_df`
3. For each new turning point identified in the loop, add that row of data to my new dataframe `turningpoints_df` so that I end up with something like this:

```
               ID    water_level    change
date           
2000-10-01      2         5.5        -0.01
2000-12-13     40        10.0         0.02
2001-02-10    150         1.1       -0.005
2001-07-29    201        12.4         0.01
...           ...         ...          ...
```

I was thinking of taking a positional approach so something like (purely illustrative):

```
turningpoints_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ID', 'water_level', 'change'])

for i in range(len(df['change'])):
    if [i-1] < 0 and [i+1] > 0:
        #this is a min point and take this row and copy to turningpoints_df
    elif [i-1] > 0 and [i+1] < 0:
        #this is a max point and take this row and copy to turningpoints_df
    else: 
        pass
```

My issue is, is that I'm not sure how to examine each value in my `change` column against the value before and after and then how to pull out that row of data into a new df when the conditions are met.

Comment: what does the data look like before the expected output? I.E. what is the input?

Comment: sharing a sample of source df would be useful (`df..loc[n:m].to_dict()`). is a*turningpoint* irrespective of *date* and *ID*.  i.e. just the order of the data in the df?

Comment: @RobRaymond it's just a daily timeseries of water levels with an additional column 'change' at the end recording the difference in water-level from the previous entry

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want to make use of the `shift` method of the DataFrame.

```py
#  shift values down by 1:

df[change_down] = df[change].shift(1)


#  shift values up by 1:
df[change_up] = df[change].shift(-1)
```

you should then be able to compare the values of each row and proceed with whatever you're trying to achieve..

```py
for row in df.iterrows():
   *check conditions here*
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some NumPy features that allows you to `roll()` a series forwards or backwards.  Then have *prev* and *next* on same row so can then use a simple function to `apply()` your logic as everything is on same row.

```py
from decimal import *
import numpy as np
d = list(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2000,1,1), dt.datetime(2010,12,31)))
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":d, "ID":[random.randint(1,200) for x in d], 
     "water_level":[round(Decimal(random.uniform(1,13)),2) for x in d], 
      "change":[round(Decimal(random.uniform(-0.05, 0.05)),3) for x in d]})

# have ref to prev and next, just apply logic
def turningpoint(r):
    r["turningpoint"] = (r["prev_change"] < 0 and r["next_change"] > 0) or \
        (r["prev_change"] > 0 and r["next_change"] < 0)
    return r

# use numpy to shift "change" so have prev and next on same row as new columns
# initially default turningpoint boolean
df = df.assign(prev_change=np.roll(df["change"],1), 
          next_change=np.roll(df["change"],-1),
          turningpoint=False).apply(turningpoint, axis=1).drop(["prev_change", "next_change"], axis=1)
# first and last rows cannot be turning points
df.loc[0:0,"turningpoint"] = False
df.loc[df.index[-1], "turningpoint"] = False

# take a copy of all rows that are turningpoints into new df with index
df_turningpoint = df[df["turningpoint"]].copy()
df_turningpoint
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to work well, I often forget about using NumPy features when working with dataframes. I'm now wondering whether I can assign a 'min' and 'max' identifier to each turning point to easily perform subsequent calculations on